# iTunes Search Lookup for all a Developers Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

Is there a way to use the iTunes Lookup to show all of the apps a Developer has? Eg:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?devid=123
```

I also tried:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/search?media=software&term=Developer Name
```

But that didn't work either. Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the details of a developer,

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=514675684
```

To get all apps by that developer,

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=514675684&entity=software
```

To get the apps based on localization,

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=514675684&entity=software&country=in
```

or, `itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?id=514675684&entity=software`

Comment: The support for country specific results has changed a little bit recently.  Apple.com supports the country code right after the domain name (instead of a url param), so the iTunes API is supporting this format too: https://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?id=514675684&entity=software

Comment: Last thing I just noticed, to get all apps by a developer "entity=software" will not return iPad only apps.  Try "entity=software,iPadSoftware" instead - this is a common question.

Comment: @TedHosmann No its returning ipad only apps also. Please check Timely HD lite is a iPad only.

Comment: Oh- you are right.  For lookup on a developer ID it makes sense that it returns all, however, on search you need both.  Take for instance a search for the "term=timely": https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=timely&entity=software or the more complete list here: https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=timely&entity=software,iPadSoftware

Answer (score 3):

If you want to search apps by developer name you need to include `attribute=softwareDeveloper`, like this: https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=milk+llc&entity=software&attribute=softwareDeveloper

(Thanks to Ted Hosmann's comment [iTunes Search Lookup for all a Developers Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596499/itunes-search-lookup-for-all-a-developers-apps#comment20559319_14596622) for helping me figure this out.)

Hey, check this out. The documentation doesn't say you can do this but `entity=softwareDeveloper` will return a list of just developers: https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=milk+llc&entity=softwareDeveloper&attribute=softwareDeveloper

Comment: Especially your last link is interesting :-)